# how to prevent tkinter from freezing when I click somewhere else?

Tags: python, tkinter, freeze

My tkinter gui starts to freeze when I click on somewhere else. Is there a way to prevent that?

Here's my code:

```
#=========================
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
import random

#=====================
root=Tk()
root.title("Wise Words")
root.geometry("500x180+360+30")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.call("wm", "attributes", ".", "-topmost", "1")

#===================
def display(random):
    if random == 1:
        return "Be wise today so you don't cry tomorrow"
    elif random == 2:
        return "Frustration is the result of failed expectations"
    elif random == 3:
        return "Wishes are possibilities. Dare to make a wish"
    if True:
        sleep(4)
        r=random.randint(1,3)
        sentence=display(r)
        label.configure(text=str(sentence))
        label.update_idletasks()

    root.after(5000, display(random))

#==================
def Click(event):
    display(random)

#====================== 
label=Button(root, fg="white", bg="blue", text="Click to start!",
    font=("Tahoma", 20, "bold"), width=40, height=4,
    wraplength=400)
label.bind("<Button-1>", Click)
label.pack()

#================
root.mainloop()
```

Note: The label for display is the Button itself, so I name it 'label'.

Comment: Why are you using `time.sleep` as well as `root.after`? Also, you never do anything with the `random` module other than refer to it and expect it to be equal to an integer (which it never will be).

Comment: When I removed the time module, it started looping without delay even with root.after was set at 5000.  That is not what I want. I use the random module to randomize the display. See in r=random.randint(1,3) and then sentence=display (r).

Comment: Oh, now I see where you do something with `random`. However, you are immediately using that in a recursive call, and then you call that function _again_ via `after`. So, you have one useful number that you send recursively after a problematic `sleep`, and then a useless value that you send via an appropriate `after`. That is not good.

Comment: Thank you, TigerhawkT3. But could you rewrite the 'def display(random)' function for me please? I've tried all day but couldn't find a better one.  It still crashes whenever I click on outside the gui.

Comment: Oh, and `display` will, when passed an integer of 1, 2, or 3, simply return a string to the caller (which is a button (which you have named `label`), that can't do anything with returned values). In addition, I'm not clear on the intended result of your code. Is the idea that the user clicks on a button and then it automatically gets new text every five seconds?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. When clicked, it will automatically randomly show the text every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing several strange things in your code:

- Using `time.sleep` in a Tkinter application
- Calling the button a label (there is a `Label` Tkinter widget)
- Binding the left mouse button to a button instead of just giving the button a `command`
- Passing the `random` module around and expecting it to evaluate to an integer
- Returning strings to a button
- Using an unconditional branching statement (`if True:`)
- Masking a module name with a parameter name
- Expecting the name `random` to refer to both the `random` module *and* a passed argument, at the same time
- Making a recursive call in a function that already calls `after`
- Leaving the button bound to a function that already schedules calls to itself with `after`, allowing you to schedule many calls
- Using an `if` structure to choose a random string instead of using `random.choice`
- Scheduling an `after` call with the result of a function call (`display(random)`) instead of the function itself

That's not necessarily a complete list.

The following fixes the above issues.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def display():
    strings = ("Be wise today so you don't cry tomorrow",
               "Frustration is the result of failed expectations",
               "Wishes are possibilities. Dare to make a wish")
    button.config(text=random.choice(strings))

    root.after(5000, display)

def click(event=None):
    button.config(command='')
    display()

root=Tk()
root.title("Wise Words")
root.geometry("500x180+360+30")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.call("wm", "attributes", ".", "-topmost", "1")
button = Button(root, fg="white", bg="blue", text="Click to start!",
    font=("Tahoma", 20, "bold"), width=40, height=4,
    wraplength=400, command=click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```